# Space between top and sub navigation

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I created a navigation with a subnavigation, see [JSFiddle with subnavigation](http://jsfiddle.net/aytaxykf/6/). I have the issue that between the top navigation with yellow background and the subnavigation with red-colored background I want to have a distance of `1px solid white` to separate both areas. At the moment this CSS definition is used

```
html, body {
  background-color: green;
}
```

I tried to put another div around `<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>` and set the `background-color: white;` but without success.

The goal is to have always a 1px solid line below the `.top-bar` area. So also when there is no subnavigation displayed, see [JSFiddle without subnavigation](http://jsfiddle.net/aytaxykf/8/), there should be this separator. I tried it to achieve it there with

```
.top-bar {
  background: yellow;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white; /*10px only to see that the border is inside the box*/
}
```

but the border is not outside the yellow `top-bar` box, it is inside, which I do not want to have. Also it would be great to have a combined so that the 1px white space between top and sb navigation is always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0e68jhbo/)

Your border solution was almost correct, just change the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property so the border isn't placed inside the `div`:

```
.top-bar {
    background: yellow; border-bottom: 10px solid white;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

This is the default value but you included Foundation that override this value with `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: This looks great! Thanks a lot! But one more question: It seems that in your working demo the space between topnav and subnav are 2 pixels, right? My CSS triangle has 1px and I want to have 1 px for both (trangle and space) so that it looks nicer. Ah, and one more thing: Normally the border is outside the box, why is it in this scenario not the case?

Comment: @Tim That line is 1px wide, it is your triangle that seems to be lighter in color (maybe because it is a diagonal line), and yes, border is outside of the box by default but you included Foundation that override it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a white border-bottom with 1px extra height on the nav:

```
.top-bar { height:71px; border-bottom:1px solid #fff; }
```

Comment: This is also working, but @totymedli is right, I have to overwrite the `box-sizing` and then I do not have to increase the height of the `top-bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Add outer Box Shadow to your top-bar. like This:

```
.top-bar{
 background: yellow;
 box-shadow:0 0 1px #fff;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to have a shadow, I want to have a 1px solid line.

Comment: If you add 1px shadow it's look same as 1px solid line

Answer (score 0):

add Z-INDEX on `.menu-center .active > a:before, .menu-center .active > a:after` and

```
    ul.sub-menu {
        background-color: red;
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        top: 100%;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aytaxykf/12/

Comment: This is only working if there is a sub navigation displayed. The case it is not displayed, is not working then.